# Select statement is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have wrote a select query using function but it is not returning data from MySQL database... can any one help me in this regard. I'm uploading screenshots.

Here is the name of my database, 'classified'
[image]

this is conn.php file

```
$conn   =   mysql_connect('localhost','root','');  
echo mysql_select_db('classified',$conn);
```

function to fetch record from database, 'adds' table
[image]

On index.php i've wrote this code.

```
include 'functions/crud_functions.php'  
  $adds = get_all_adds();  
 foreach($adds as $add) {

<tr>                 
    <td><?php echo $add['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $add['ad_title'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $add['cat_id'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $add['ad_description'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $add['avatar'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $add['price'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $add['contact'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $add['name'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $add['time'];?></td>
    <td><a href="#">Edit </a> | <a href="#">Del </a></td>
</tr>
```

but this is not displaying records.

Comment: Where is your query?

Comment: where is your $conn being used??

Comment: Is your query does not return results when it is run through DB end

Comment: We need to know the codes inside get_all_adds()

Comment: I've uploaded image of function, in which query is written.. #Mr. Engineer

Comment: you have only tagged `sql server`, `mysql` and `oracle`. Looks like you missed out `sybase` and `db2`

Comment: No, it is not returning any data..#NewUser 2

Comment: I removed them. Let OP start over and tag just one of them...

Comment: i've uploaded the image of function, get_all_adds(); ... #budiantoip.

Comment: get_all_adds();  returns only TRUE or FALSE not data

Comment: get_all_adds();  is the name of my function i wrote myself..then what should i do to return data ?#Rakesh

Comment: you need to write "return $data" instead of return TRUE;

Comment: change the function return part as `if ($result) { while(){....} return $data;} else { return false ;}` and do the loop as `$adds = get_all_adds();  if (false !== $adds){ foreach(){....} }`

Comment: You wrote `get_all_adds` function as a boolean function. So it's return value always be `True` or `False`, Neither records from  your database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change :

```
if ($result) {
  return TRUE;
} else {
  return FALSE;
}
```

into this :

```
if ($result) {
  return $data;
} else {
  return array();
}
```

Comment: Thank you [Muhammad Muazzam](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2456918/muhammad-muazzam) for your edit, didn't notice he uses foreach after returning the result :)